# When does gravity based on a specific function result in periodic orbits?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Suppose there is a planet orbiting around a massive star, such that the star pulls the planet with a force proportional to a function $g(x)$ of the distance from the star (ignore the planet's force on the star). Newtonian gravity, which corresponds to $g(x) = \frac{k}{x^2},$ guarantees that every bounded orbit is periodic. $g(x) = kx$ also guarantees this because the components of the planet's motion are simple harmonic motion with the same period.  For what functions $g(x)$ is the orbit guaranteed to be periodic if it is bounded, no matter what the initial position and velocity of the planet are?

Comment: You want [Bertrand's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem). These are the only two potentials that give the physics you want.

Comment: I never knew that this exact problem has been solved before.

Comment: It's not too well known! I am currently teaching multivariable calculus and we went through Kepler's laws in full gory detail. I went through a physics degree without seeing all of the details on these topics somehow. Some keywords you want to look up are "central force" in conjunction with "stable orbits". There is some really interesting math in this arena.